# How can a simple assignment cause a segmentation fault?

Tags: c

I'm making a program to split a file into lexemes but I'm unfamiliar with C and I'm getting a weird segmentation error. The following code runs and prints:

```
1
2
Segmentation Fault: 11
```

I've looked up other causes to segmentation faults and I'm not doing anything to an array after 2. What am I doing wrong? How can a simple assignment cause a segmentation fault?

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define CHAR_CODE 1
#define NUM_CODE 2
#define RESERVED_CHAR_CODE 3
#define SPACE_CODE 4
#define ERR_CODE 5

char token[16];
char line[128];
int lineLen = 0;
int counter = 0;
FILE *file;

void cleanToken(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 16; i++){
        token[i] = 0;
    }
}

void cleanLine(){
    for(int i = 0 ; i < 128; i++){
        line[i] = 0;
    }
}

void next(){
    cleanToken();
    printf("1\n");
    char c;
    if(counter == lineLen){
        printf("2\n");
        lineLen = 0;
        printf("3");
        cleanLine();
        printf("4");
        counter = 0;
        while((c=getc(file)) != 10 && c != EOF){
            if(c!=32){
                line[lineLen] = c;
                lineLen++;
            }
            printf("%d\n", lineLen);
        }
        printf("%s\n", line);
    }
    c = line[counter];
    int type = getType(c);
    while(getType(c)==type){
        token[counter] = c; 
        counter = counter + 1;
        c = line[counter];
        if(c == EOF | c == 4 | type == RESERVED_CHAR_CODE){
            break;  
        }
    }
}

int getType(int c){
    if((c > 96 & c < 123) | (c>64 & c < 91)){
        return CHAR_CODE;
    } else if(c < 58 & c > 46){
        return NUM_CODE;
    } else if(c == 32){
        return SPACE_CODE;
    } else if(c == 33 | c == 34 | (c > 36 & c < 44) | c == 45 | c == 47 | (c > 58 & c < 63)){

        return RESERVED_CHAR_CODE;  
    } else {
        return ERR_CODE;
    }
}

int main(){
    int c;
    FILE* file;
    file = fopen("test.txt", "r");
    for(int i = 0; i < 10 ;i++){
        next();
        printf("%s\n", token);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Compile with all warning s enabled.

Comment: What's in your `test.txt` file ?

Comment: Please indent your code, provide us with a minimal example ... That said, a seg fault for such  a simple `printf` statement usually means that your `token` is not properly null terminate.

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should avoid magic numbers such as in this line: `if(c == 33 | c == 34 | (c > 36 & c < 44) | c == 45 | c == 47 | (c > 58 & c < 63))`. What is `33`, `34` etc. ? BTW: instead of write 65 you can write `'A'`.

Comment: Also, I'm fairly certain you want to be using the `||` operator (logical OR) as opposed to `|` (bitwise OR).

Comment: when you compile with all the warnings enabled, you will see a lot of this kind of warning: `warning: suggest parentheses around comparison in operand of ...`  Which means add the necessary parens.  and the warning: `warning: implicit declaration of function 'getType' [-Wimplicit-function-declaration]` which means the top of the program needs a prototype statement for that function. and the function: `getc()` returns an `int` not a `char` so the variable `c` should be declared via: `int c;`  Suggest reading/understanding the man page for system functions so they are used correctly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There are a number of problems in your code, most of which will be shown by using `-Wall` when you compile, but specifically, the crash is being caused by attempting to access the global variable `file`, which has not been initialized.

You shadowed it in `main()` with another variable with the same name.  You initialized that one, but **not the global one being accessed by `next()`**.

Also, your `printf` statements are insufficient for debugging, as there is no guarantee that the output buffer will be flushed to your console before the program crashes.  If you add `\n` to the `printf("3") and printf("4")` lines, you will see that they get printed before the crash.  Alternatively, you could call `fflush(stdout)` after the `printf()` calls to ensure that they are printed.  By doing this, you will see that the crash is not happening as a result of the assignment as it appears.

A debugger such as `gdb` would be very helpful in debugging your code.

Answer (score 3):

**EDIT**

Derp.  Just saw eddiem's answer, and he's right - that's the real problem in your code.

However, you should still add the `lineLen` check in your loop.

**ORIGINAL**

Gonna bet real money the problem is here:

```
while((c=getc(file)) != 10 && c != EOF){
    if(c!=32){
        line[lineLen] = c;  
        lineLen++;
    }
```

What happens if the file contains more than 128 characters on a single line?  You wind up writing past the end of your array, which can cause all kinds of mayhem.

You need to add a check to make sure you're not exceeding your array bounds:

```
while ( lineLen < 128 && ( c = getc( file ) ) != 10 && c != EOF ) { ... }
```

You're not seeing `3` and `4` print out because you don't have a newline in those `printf` statements.  `stdout` is usually line-buffered, which means output won't appear on the terminal unless the buffer is full or a newline character is sent.

Answer (score 2):

You have two different `file` variables, one global one declared at the top of your program, and one global one in the `main` function.

And in the `next` function you use the global `file` which has never been assigned.

```
#include <stdio.h>
...
FILE *file;  // <<< global one
...


int main() {
  int c;
  FILE* file;   // <<<local one

  file = fopen("x.txt", "r");
   ...
  return 0;
}
```

Yet another example that shows why abusing global variables leads to problems.

There are most likely other problems.